# How to test for SNR for an ADC

Tags: frequency-spectrum, snr

I have a 24 bit ADC and I need to test for signal-to-noise ratio. I have a function generator which can generate different signals, so can I simply take 10*log<sub>10</sub>(power of signal/power of noise)?

When I'm taking the power of the noise should I ground the ADC input or keep it open?

I'm calculating the power of the signal by taking an FFT of the signal.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you're going to measure the signal to noise of an ADC by comparing the output with a known signal to an output with a nominally zero signal, then you should maintain the input at the same impedance both times.

In your case, it's probably best to capture the signal with the signal generator outputting a sine wave, and then set the amplitude of the signal generator to zero and repeat.  If that makes you uncomfortable, then you should replace the input to the ADC with a dummy load that has the same impedance as the signal generator's output.

Comment: I answered your question as posed, but note that (A) there are a lot of methods for measuring noise, depending on your problem and the preferences of the people involved, (B) it's tricky, (C) A and B, combined, means that there is a **lot** of information out there on how to do it.  **My** opinion is that because it is very difficult to build circuitry that's good to 24 bits you probably want to test your setup using your signal conditioning circuitry, and you want to be very careful about checking that your signal generator is good to 24 bits itself.